# Call async await method in sync calling method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

This is only the idea on what im doing in a window service.
I get the idea from this [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2287) to do it in parallel processing.

I have two different method and a model class.

Model Class code:

```
public class Email(){
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Methods is something like this:

```
public void LoadData(){
    while(Main.IsProcessRunning){
        // 1. Get All Emails
        var emails = new dummyRepositories().GetAllEmails(); //This will return List<Emails>.
        // 2. Send it
        // After sending assume that the data will move to other table so it will not be query again for the next loop.
        SendDataParallel(emails);//this will function async? even though the calling method is sync.

        // This will continue here or wait until it already send?
        // If it will continue here even though it will not send already
        // So there's a chance to get the email again for the next loop and send it again?
    }
}

//This will send email at parallel
public async void SendDataParallel(IList<Email> emails){
    var allTasks = emails.Select(SendDataAsync);
    await TaskEx.WhenAll(allTasks);
}

//Assume this code will send email asynchronously. (this will not send email, for sample only)
public async void SendDataAsync(Email email){
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.PostAsync(email);
    }
}
```

I only want to get all queued emails then send it in parallel then wait until it already send.
I'm avoiding using `foreach` on every email that I get.

Comment: What is the question or problem?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel already edited.,.

Comment: @janmvtrinidad There is still no question here.

Comment: @AntP i put question as a comment in code.,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start at the bottom:

1. You dispose your client before you actually finish receiving the `HttpResponseMessage` asynchronously. You'll need to make your method `async Task` and `await` inside:

   ```
   public async Task SendDataAsync(Email email)
   {
       using (var client = new HttpClient())
       {
           var response = await client.PostAsync(email);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Currently, your `SendDataParallel` doesn't compile. Again, it needs to return a `Task`:

   ```
   public Task SendEmailsAsync(IList<Email> emails)
   {
       var emailTasks = emails.Select(SendDataAsync);
       return Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
   }
   ```
3. At the top, you'll need to `await` on `SendEmailsAsync`:

   ```
   public async Task LoadDataAsync()
   {
       while (Main.IsProcessRunning)
       {
           var emails = new dummyRepositories().GetAllEmails(); 
           await SendEmailsAsync(emails);
       }
   }
   ```

**Edit:**

If you're running this inside a windows service, you can offload it to `Task.Run` and use the `async` keyword:

```
var controller = new Controller();
_processThread = Task.Run(async () => await controller.LoadDataAsync());
```

Comment: It's okay to add static type for LoadDataAsync.,?

Comment: You want the method to be `static`?

Comment: I will be using LoadData to call as a background service in windows service.,.

Comment: @janmvtrinidad Ok, but what does that have to do with a `static` method?

Comment: I will create a Thread like this one `_processThread = new Thread(Controllers.LoadData) { IsBackground = true };`, it needs to be a static to place LoadData as parameters for Thread.

Comment: @janmvtrinidad It doesn't have to be. You can create an instance of your controller first. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't your compiler highlight your code with errors?

If you mark your method as async while it doesn't return any value, you should set your return type as Task, not void:

```
public async Task SendDataParallel(IList<Email> emails){
    var allTasks = emails.Select(SendDataAsync);
    await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
}
```

Your second method also shoud return a Task, otherwise what you want to (a)wait in the first method?

```
public async Task SendDataAsync(Email email){
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        return client.PostAsync(email);
    }
}
```

Now you can Select all your SendDataAsync tasks in SendDataParallel and .Wait()  it's task in LoadData in synchronious mode:

```
public void LoadData(){
    while(Main.IsProcessRunning){
        var emails = new dummyRepositories().GetAllEmails(); //This will return List<Emails>.
        SendDataParallel(emails).Wait();
    }
}
```

More information you can find reading answers in other SO questions and docs on MSDN:

- [Can somebody please explain async / await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177891/can-somebody-please-explain-async-await)
- [Brief explanation of Async/Await in .Net 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082074/brief-explanation-of-async-await-in-net-4-5)
- [how to and when use `async` and `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-to-and-when-use-async-and-await)
- [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx)

And as you used LINQ's Select() which is based on foreach cycle next article also could be useful:
[Nested task inside loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460464/nested-task-inside-loop)

Comment: I will use an wait() on my LoadData().., I think it will have an error on SendDataAsync, there is no await keyword on return.., Anyway thanks for your solution.,.